# How to handle ACTION_DOWN and ACTION_MOVE independently

Tags: android

I asked a similar question before but the answer was not very helpful and I can't find any solution for this problem.

I want to know a method to detect ACTION_DOWN when we only touch a certain view and to detect ACTION_MOVE when we only move our finger on screen, because all I am getting is ACTION_DOWN and ACTION_MOVE being called at the same time when I place my finger on the view.

can anyone please post a simple code for how to do that.

Comment: As mentioned on your similar question, you need to set a threshold size below which movement is ignored.

Comment: @meatspace and how to do that I can't figure it out?

Answer (score 0):

That are raw motion events. You can probably use `GestureDetector` and detect click and swipe.

Problem is that `ACTION_MOVE` will be called when any move is detected, for example applying just a little more pressure when touching screen might move touch point few pixels around.

Comment: can I make an if statement with a certain threshold of this uncertainty in finger pressure which is causing move to be triggered.If yes then how can I accomplish that .

Comment: It's not just about pressure, user might move finger few millimeters (even if he's performing touch/click). What you could do is `getX` and `getY` from MotionEvent when user `ACTION_MOVE` and track delta from X and Y from `ACTION_DOWN`. Then you could define some threshold at which you would say: ok, this is not touch, this user is moving his finger.

Comment: I understand what you said can you show me a sample code on that cause I have some problems with touch events.

Comment: just let me know what to put in DOWN and MOVE , thanks.

Comment: Have two fields where you will store starting X and Y when happens ACTION_DOWN  (getX and getY methods). Then, when ACTION_MOVE events are happening check their X and Y, and then compare it to starting X and Y. You can disregard movements if change of X and Y was like 10px or something like that, basically you need to play with this threshold number. I would still use GestureDetector for case like this.

Comment: so you think gesture detector is more stable, and swipe is equivalent to moving finger ?

Comment: GestureDetector is addition so you don't have to work with raw events. It will differentiate clicks, double clicks, flings and other for you. Check this for more: https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/detector.html

Comment: I found out many gestures available but it seems that there is 4 methods to swipe(swipe left, right, up, down)....but in ontouch listeners only action move is needed to handle move so , which gesture is equivalent to ACTION_MOVE ?